# Interaction b/w two forms in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket-1.5

This may sound a bit odd, I have two forms in a single HTML page with different wicket id's.Is it possible that when a user clicks a button eg.(save) it saves the data from both the forms together.I can't keep a single form.
I am new to wicket,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add both forms to a third form as Wicket supports nested forms. This way your button could be attached to the outer form submitting all of the form data.